# File upload-how to create destination folder with user name

Tags: php

I need to upload file using php and I done it...Now my problem is I want to create a new folder for every user let me explain to you how??

My task is for user can login and access their account and file uploads. If the user will upload any file it goes to my destination folder named as 'uploads'. Now I want to create new folder inside the uploads folder with the particular username who uploads the file... so I want to create new folder for each and every users with their username... Can anyone tell me how to do this???

This is my php code for destination :

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], '../uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name']))    
{

echo '{"status":"success"}';

exit;    
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
//check if the folder not exists then create it
if (!file_exists('<rootpath>/<username>')) { //<rootpath> will be the path from document root and <username> will be the username you want
   mkdir('<rootpath>/<username>');
}
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], '<path>/<username>/'.$_FILES['upl']['name']))    // <path> be the relative path
{

echo '{"status":"success"}';

exit;    
}
```

Suppose You want to upload the file inside `uploads/username` folder.

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads';
```

Now create the folder -

```
mkdir($path."/".$username); //$username be the username you want
```

Now upload the file

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$username.'/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply...still strugging with the code... may i know how declare my root path as well as username inside the if loop???

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `mkdir` function. You can create a directory by using:

`mkdir('/path/to/dir', 0700);`

as noted in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).

Comment: Set the third argument to TRUE if you want to create directories recursive.

Comment: @HarryFink absolutely, hence the link to PHP documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mkdir()` function to create a folder upon user registration.

Upon login create a `$_SESSION` variable storing the username.

When using `move_uploaded_file()` function add session variable to path.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], '../uploads/'.$_SESSION['username'].'/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: Ya.. one more help.... May i know how to get my username variable instead of <username> ??

Comment: Why don't you on login you set a $_SESSION variable and store username then use it in as such : '../uploads/'.$_SESSION['username'].'/...'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SGT... I got the answer with this code

```
$userfolder = $_SESSION['email'];
//echo $userfolder;
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'register/uploads';

if (!file_exists('$path')) {
    mkdir($path."/".$userfolder);
}
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], '../uploads/'.$userfolder.'/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    }
```

Thanks Again